# Sequential receiving of elements from the two-dimensional array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm a beginner in Java, and I need to write a `next()` method, which will return current value from 2D array.

For example, we may have:

```
int[][] values = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

When we are using `next()` at the first time, it returns `1`, second use - `2`, third - `3`, etc.

My solution is to make 1D array from that 2D array:

```
 public int[] convert(int[][] array) {

        // At first, count number of all cells to set length for new 1D array.

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        // Now we have length. Creating new array and filling it with data from all arrays.

        int[] result = new int[count];
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                result[index] = array[i][j];
                index++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And then just get a value from that new 1D array (`position` is a class field `= 0`, `values` is also a class field - `int[][] values`):

```
public int next() {
        int[] tmp = convert(values);
        int result = tmp[position];
        position++;
        return result;
    }
```

But it is obvious that this solution is not the best. Is there a way to do this without conversation of the arrays?

Something similar to the methods of Iterator's `next()` and `hasNext()`?

**Update.** I wrote some bad code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
public class ArrayConverter {
    private final int[][] values;
    private int upper = 0;
    private int lower = -1;

    public ArrayConverter(int[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int next() {
        lower++;
        int result = 0;
        try {
            result = values[upper][lower];
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException a) {
            lower = 0;
            upper++;
            try {
                result = values[upper][lower];
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException r) {
                upper = 0;
                lower = -1;
                System.out.print("Reached the end of data. Indexes will be zeroed.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

That code is bad because of try/catch blocks, and I prefer to avoid it. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a `List` then you will avoid to count the number of your elements :

```
int[][] array = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}; 
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int[] array1 : array) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        list.add(array1[j]);
    }
}
```

Then you can get your values with `list.get(position);`

Comment: Actually, I wanted to avoid of creating any new arrays and copying of data.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Tian mentioned. it can be done by Stream API shortly:

```
OfInt iter = Stream.of(a).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).iterator();

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    iter.nextInt();
}
```